# What abilities does being the default "Assist" app give to an app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-permissions

I need to know what can I do with my app if the user changes my app to default assist app.

I'd like to know what abilities this role grants, preferably with the source of the information.

Comment: can u explain it in detail brother ?

Comment: you can see the default assist apps in [this image](https://www.androidguys.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Android-Search-default-06.png). I want to know what can I do with my app if it is an assist app

Comment: u mean what should you do to your app to appear as assist app right ??

Comment: actually no; I need to turn on and turn off AirPlane mode without root access and I know one way to do it, is to be default assist app. but I don't know how to do that if my app was an assist app.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this will make your application start when 3 things happen:

1. When the user long-clicks the home button in the navigation bar
2. When the user presses the assistant button on their Device ( if their device has it )
3. when an another application starts the assist app ( your app ) using this code: `startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND"));`

Comment: I know these, but I want to know what can I do as an assist app

Comment: Honestly.. I don't know more about that